# I can't acces with public ip to my server from my LAN

Tags: routes, server, nat, enroute

I have a server in my house. I requested a public IP to my internet provider. I activated the port forwarding, and magic I can access to my server from any internet connection, but...I cannot access if I'm connected to my LAN.

I cannot access to my server with the public ip if I'm connected at home LAN. I reviewed all the router configurations and I cannot solve the problem. Sometimes I receive a timeout exception, others configurations returned me a redirection to my local ip gateway with an intercepted message (192.168.1.1/intercepted). But I cannot see any solution.

I call my internet provider a couple of times and they told me that the configuration is fine because I can access out of the LAN.

I tried to set a static routing but as I'm not an expert, maybe I'm missing something.

Thank you in advance, and any help will be more than welcome.

**UPDATE**

Ok, it seems to be the NAT loopback what I need to activate. What is the problem now? My internet company provider is telling me that my router hasn't that option. (Sercomm FG824CD)